# Why is the caret invisible in a contenteditable with position:relative?

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

When a `contenteditable` element has `position: relative` and a background color, the caret is invisible when it's placed in that element. Here's an example:

```css
.bug {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  This has caret
  <span class="bug">no caret here?!</span>
  this has caret
</div>
```

My first thought was "this is a browser bug", but it's the exact same bug on Chrome and Firefox!

**What causes the caret to disappear? And is there a workaround?**

Comment: Wow, it's kind of awesome there is a full browsers consensus on such a weird behavior, moreover in this interop' hell that is `contenteditable`, one of the rare spots implementations do agree on... (seeing you do develop for macOS, I should note I only tested on macOS, maybe it's OS dependent).

Comment: Just found this reported as a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806904

Comment: It's also reported for Webkit: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1748239

Comment: I just reported it for Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1748239

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know the exact cause of the issue but you can fix it in multiple ways.

My previous explanation (*maybe wrong*) :

> This isn't a bug, you put the `background color` on a `<span>` tag (in
> `position:relative`) inside a **contenteditable** div element and so the
> span is on top of the **contenteditable** div.

I still think is related to the `z-index` since we can see on the image below the red background on top of the Chrome focus border:

[image]

### Remove `position:relative`

Removing `position:relative` of the `<span>` fix the issue:

```css
.no-bug {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  This has caret
  <span class="no-bug">This has caret !</span>
  this has caret
</div>
```

### Adding a `z-index` to the `<span>` element

Adding a negative `z-index` also fix the issue:

```css
.no-bug {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -10;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  This has caret
  <span class="no-bug">This has caret !</span>
  this has caret
</div>
```

### Adding a `display: inline-block` to the `<span>` element

Adding a `display: inline-block` (or `display: block`) fix the issue:

```css
.no-bug {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  This has caret
  <span class="no-bug">This has caret !</span>
  this has caret
</div>
```

### Others Stackoverflow related questions

- [Edit cursor not displayed on Chrome in contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897883/edit-cursor-not-displayed-on-chrome-in-contenteditable)
- [contenteditable cursor doesn't appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139303/contenteditable-cursor-doesnt-appear)

Comment: But the span also has its own `.isContentEditable` set to `true`. The caret is inside that span element, as you can check using the Selection API, it should logically be over this element's background.

Comment: @Kaiido this is true, I answer was incorrect, I updated my answer with ways to fix the issue but don't know exactly what is the origin of the issue.

Comment: Thanks @BenSouchet - `z-index: -1` fixes the issue for me! `display: inline-block` is not an option for me due to [a different browser bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1088403). What a bizarre issue! I think I'll report this as a browser bug anyway ...